# Ionicons not working Ionic V4 after NPM update

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionicons

I had an issue with some Ionicons that were not displayed but now none of them are showing on my testing environment. None of them 

My angular.json looks likwe this:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "assets": [
              "src/app-config.json",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],

        "test": {
          "options": {
            "assets": [
              "src/app-config.json",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have executed npm install and npm update with no success.

see the error screenshot

[image]

Thanks!

EDIT:

This is my package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@capacitor/android": "^1.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/network-interface": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.10",
    "@ionic/lab": "^2.0.19",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-networkinterface": "^2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ionicons": "^5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-run": "^0.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
}
```

It seems to be V4 still, should i update to 5?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be caused by Ionicons v5 update. What are your @ionic/angular + @angular versions in package.json?

Comment: If you want for browser , remove the www folder and build as ionic build --prod then ionic serve, and for mobile remove the platform then rebuild it. And check your icon names since also they have changed (ionicons.com)

Comment: @TomasVancoillie is right, but the Angular Version is unimportant. Check which Version of @ionic/angular you have installed.